# Applescript renames a file, gives errors?

Tags: file, applescript, rename

I have this simple code in apple script which when run is supposed to rename the file. Instead it gives me an error Can’t get file "Volumes:Projects:Projects:1.pdf".

```
set ff to file "Volumes:Projects:Projects:1.pdf"
set ss to "Volumes:Projects:Projects:1.pdf"
set name of ff to ss
```

Answer (score 1):

Using the following *example* **AppleScript** *code*, with the existence of the *file* set to `ff` at the shown path:

```
set ff to POSIX path of "Volumes:Projects:Projects:1.pdf"
set ss to "2.pdf"

tell application "System Events" to set name of file ff to ss
```

Shows the following *Event* in **Script Editor**:

```
tell application "System Events"
    set name of file "/Volumes/Projects/Projects/1.pdf" to "2.pdf"
end tell
```

Looking in **Finder**, `1.pdf` was renamed to `2.pdf`, as expected in this example.

---

Update: Note that vadian make a good point in 2 about the hierarchy of an **HFS path**, and is in part why I chose to covert it to a **POSIX path**. I also prefer to use **System Events** as it typically handle file operations faster than **Finder** and will work with both **HFS** style and **POSIX** style *paths*.

In other words, with **System Events** the following works:

```
tell application "System Events" to set name of file "Projects:Projects:1.pdf" to "2.pdf"

tell application "System Events" to set name of file "/Volumes/Projects/Projects/1.pdf" to "2.pdf"
```

But this too, even though malformed, works:

```
tell application "System Events" to set name of file "Volumes:Projects:Projects:1.pdf" to "2.pdf"
```

However, with **Finder**, only a proper **HFS path** works without error, it can't handle a **POSIX path** because it doesn't understand it as it's not in **Finder**'s AppleScript Dictionary.

That said, one should always make sure the information being passed is properly formed even when a malformed path would work in this example with **System Events**, it's not a good habit to get into!

Answer (score 1):

Three major issues.

1. To rename a file you have to tell `Finder` or `System Events` to do that.
2. A HFS path (colon separated) starts **always** with a disk name, never with *Volumes*.
3. To rename a file set the `name` property to a file **name** rather than to a **full path**.

---

Actually your example does nothing.

This snippet renames the file `1.pdf` in folder "Projects" on disk `Projects` to `2.pdf`

```
tell application "Finder"
    set name of file "Projects:Projects:1.pdf" to "2.pdf"
end tell
```